# How to get users to whom a SharePoint file in a document library is shared with

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, spfx-tooling

I am making a accordion for a SharePoint doc lib. Accordion expands on folder/subfolder/subfolder....(up to 3 level) and also shows all files in tree like structure.
I have use following api call to accomplish that.
`/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('${folderUrl}')$expand=Files,Folders/Files,Folders/Folders/Files,Folders/Folders/Folders/Files`

Now, I also want to get the list of users with whome a specific file is shared with. (We are planning to have a pop and on file click popup shows list of user with whome the file is shared) How shall i do that as I am not finding any proper reference. I do have listid, itemid ant tried using [this](http://%3Csitecollection%3E/%3Csite%3E/_api/web/lists(listid)/items(itemid)/effectiveBasePermissionsForUI) (idk if it is tobe used for sol or not) but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is an OOTB way for your reference:

1.Click the Information icon next to the file and select **Manage access**, the Manage Access panel opens.

[image]

2.The **Links Giving Access section** shows the links that have permissions to the file or folder. Click the ellipsis (...) to see the users that the link has been shared with.
[image]

3.You can view **Shared with** section in the upcoming panel:
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Actually we are preparing spfx webpart and want to integrate this in our solution. Can we get this by library id and item uuid?